# react z-index css button value not working

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs

I am trying to design a responsive website with react using no bootstrap or other plugins, just css/js/html. So far my responsive layout works but a button

```
{/* Open & Close Sidebar Button */}
                    <button className="sidebarBtn" onClick={sideNavClicked}>
                        <a className={`chevron-char ${toggleSidebarIcon ? 'sidebar-collapsed' : ' '} `} >&gt;</a>
                    </button>
```

Appears behind the sidebar when I want it infront
[image]

I've tried setting and specifying the z-index value for all import elements but no luck, can anyone give advice how to solve this in react

my component file Mainsidebar.js and MainSidebar.css:

```js
import React from 'react'
import "./MainSidebar.css"
import ProgressiveImage from "./ProgressiveImage";
import { Link, useNavigate } from "react-router-dom";
const MainSidebar = ({ children }) => {

    function getRandomImage() {

    }

    //toggle open/close sidenav depending on current status
    function sideNavClicked() {
        console.log('sideNavClicked()')
        setShowSideNav(!showSideNav)
        setToggleSidebarIcon(!toggleSidebarIcon)

    }

    function menuItemClicked() {
        console.log('toggleMenuItem()')
        setToggleMenuItem(!toggleMenuItem)
    }

    const [showSideNav, setShowSideNav] = React.useState(true);
    const [toggleMenuItem, setToggleMenuItem] = React.useState(true);
    const [toggleSidebarIcon, setToggleSidebarIcon] = React.useState(false);

    return (
        <>
            <div className="main-content">
                {/* Sidebar */}
                <div id="mySidebar" className={` super-animation sidebar ${showSideNav ? 'sidebar-show' : ' '} `} >
                    {/* Martin Barker */}
                    <div className="color0">
                        {/* Name Text */}
                        <a href="#" className='sidebar-header color1'>Martin Barker</a>
                    </div>

                    <a href="#" className='color2'>About</a>

                    <a className="color3" data-ulid="expand_this" onClick={menuItemClicked} href="#">Projects X</a>
                    <ul className={` ${toggleMenuItem ? 'ul-show' : ' '} `}>
                        <li><a href="#">tagger.site</a></li>
                        <li>
                            <Link to="/rendertune">RenderTune</Link>
                        </li>
                        <li><a href="#">Vinyl2Digital</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Popularify</a></li>
                    </ul>
                    <a href="#">Blog</a>
                    <a href="#">Contact</a>

                    {/* Image Display LazyLoad */}
                    <div className='imgColor'>
                        <button >Refresh Colors</button>
                        <br></br>
                        <ProgressiveImage
                            className={"colorSrcImg"}
                            alt={"color source image"}
                            overlaySrc={
                                require("../aesthetic-images/thumbnails/418112_thumb.jpg")
                            }
                            src={
                                require("../aesthetic-images/418112.jpg")
                            }
                        />

                    </div>
                </div>

                {/* Page Contents */}
                <div id="main" className={` super-animation ${showSideNav ? 'show-sidebar' : ' '} `}>

                    {/* Open & Close Sidebar Button */}
                    <button className="sidebarBtn" onClick={sideNavClicked}>
                        <a className={`chevron-char ${toggleSidebarIcon ? 'sidebar-collapsed' : ' '} `} >&gt;</a>
                    </button>

                    <div>
                        <h1>responsive page content responsive page content responsive page content </h1>
                        <br></br>
                        <h4>responsive page content </h4>
                    </div>

                    {/* 
                    <div className={`  ${!toggleSidebarIcon ? ' ' : '  '}`}>
                        {children}
                    </div>
                    */}

                </div>
            </div>
        </>
    )
}

export default MainSidebar
```

```css
.colorSrcImg{
    width:100px
}

.sidebar-txt{
    font-size: 7px;

}

html,
body {
  font-family: "Lato", sans-serif;
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
}

.super-animation{
  -webkit-transition: -webkit-transform 300ms ease;
  -webkit-transition-duration: 300ms;
  -moz-transition: -moz-transform 300ms ease;
  transition: transform 300ms ease;
}

.main-content{
  margin: 0;
  display: flex;
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

.sidebar {
  height: 100%;
  width: 200px;
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 1;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  background-color: #111;
  overflow-x: hidden;
  
  right: 0;
  -webkit-transform: translate3d(calc(-100%), 0, 0);
  -moz-transform: translate3d(calc(-100%), 0, 0);
  transform: translate3d(calc(-100%), 0, 0);
}

.sidebar.sidebar-show{
  -webkit-transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
  -moz-transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
  transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
}

.sidebar a {
  padding: 8px 8px 8px 32px;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 19px;
  color: #818181;
  display: block;
  transition: 0.3s;
}

.sidebar a:hover {
  color: #f1f1f1;
}

.chevron-char{
  height:22px;
  color:white;
}


.sidebar-collapsed {
  transform: rotate(180deg);
  transition: all 0.25s ease-in-out;
  display:inline-block;
}

.sidebar .closebtn {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 25px;
  font-size: 36px;
  margin-left: 50px;
}

.sidebarBtn {
  border-radius: 50%;
  font-size: 20px;
  cursor: pointer;

  padding: 10px 15px;
  margin-left: -40px;
  border: none;

  background-color: pink;
  color: yellow;


  z-index:100!important;

  box-shadow: 0px 1px 4px 1px rgb(0 0 0 / 30%);
  cursor: pointer;
}

.sidebarBtn:hover {
  background-color: #444;
}

#main {
    padding-left: 16px;
    z-index:9999!important;
}

#main.show-sidebar{
  -webkit-transform: translate3d(200px, 0, 0);
  -moz-transform: translate3d(200px, 0, 0);
  transform: translate3d(200px, 0, 0);
  margin-right: 190px;
  min-width: 15px;
  overflow: overlay;
}

.main-content .sidebar ul{
  margin: 0;
  max-height: 0px;
  overflow: hidden;
  transition: max-height 200ms ;
}

.main-content .sidebar ul.ul-show{
  transition: max-height 200ms ease-in;
  max-height: 400px;
}

/* On smaller screens, where height is less than 450px, change the style of the sidenav (less padding and a smaller font size) */
@media screen and (max-height: 450px) {
  .sidebar {padding-top: 15px;}
  .sidebar a {font-size: 18px;}
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: z-index property only works in an element with position property set to absolute, fixed, sticky, relative or a flex item. Here your sidebarBtn css class doesn't follow any above criteria. Try setting your sidebarBtn to position:relative.

Comment: tried adding position:relative to to sidebarBtn and it did not work. but adding `display: table;` to `id="main"` did make the pink button appear on the front? I would not like to keep that as a solution sounds very hacky

Comment: try changing the z-index of the parent, or parent's parent.